# How to navigate Programmatically in Vue.js with added Hash

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Lets say i have an component. In this component there is an

Profile.vue

```
<a @click="openSettingsPage('#editMyProfile')">
```

```
openSettingsPage(hash) {
  return this.$router.push({ path: '/settings/profile', name: 'Settings', params: { hash: hash } });
},
```

Router.js

```
path: '/settings/profile:hash',
name: 'Settings',
component: Settings,
```

What this actually returns is

```
/settings/profile%23editMyProfile
```

So my Question is how do i get rid of this stupid escapes ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the examples, you are trying to pass a hash through params, but in the configuration you indicate that a parameter is expected. If you want to pass exactly the hash, then here's an example:

```js
openSettingsPage(hash) {
  return this.$router.push({ name: 'Settings', hash })
}
```

If as a parameter:

```js
openSettingsPage(hash) {
  return this.$router.push({ name: 'Settings', params: { hash } })
}
```

Hash and params are different things. Read the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) and decide what works best for you.

And you also didn't include a slash before the parameter:

```js
{
  path: '/settings/profile/:hash',
  name: 'Settings',
  component: Settings,
}
```